# javax.net.ssl.SSLException when using REST client in PyCharm

Tags: java, macos, pycharm, osx-yosemite, sslexception

**Update**:

As per JetBrains [support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/requests/59722), JDK 8 will solve the issue but now the font rendering is horrible. I'll leave this here for later updates.

---

I'm trying to send an HTTP**S** request with REST client in PyCharm in OSX Yosemite, but it gives this:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not
>   generate DH keypair

I have `java version "1.6.0_65"` currently installed and requests to HTTP urls work just fine.